GKE Ingress Error: "Missing one or more resources. If resource creation takes longer than expected, you might have an invalid configuration."
I am using helm to deploy an GCE external ingress on a GKE  cluster but i kept getting this error Missing one or more resources. If resource creation takes longer than expected, you might have an invalid configuration.. Here are my details:
Deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service-backend
        date: "{{ now | unixEpoch }}"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: service-backend
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}@sha256:{{ .Values.image.sha | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          env:
            {{- toYaml .Values.env | nindent 12 }}

Service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: service-backend

Ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-ingress-staging
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-staging-ip
spec:
  ingressClassName: "gce"
  rules:
    - host: staging-api.myhost.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-service
                port:
                  number: 80

Current Status:

Ingress is not routing traffic as expected.
I see errors related to missing resources or timeout issues.
Ingress address is missing
Ingress not getting mapped to the static IP
Other components like the service and pods seem to be working fine.

What I've Tried:

Verified that the backend service and pod are healthy.
Checked for any syntax errors or misconfigurations in the Ingress YAML.
Uninstalled the entire deployment/release via helm
Re-created the entire cluster.


I ran into a similar issue a few days ago. I'm not sure the underlying problem is the same but you can try the following:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-ingress-staging
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-staging-ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: staging-api.myhost.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-service
                port:
                  number: 80

In the snippet above, I just removed the spec.ingressClassName and replaced it with an annotation. Although the annotation has been deprecated by kubernetes, GKE still relies on it and states that it must be used instead.
Alternatively, you can find configuration examples for different scenarios in this repo.
I hope this helps.
